# Luhn Algorithm sometimes work sometimes fail

Tags: c, algorithm, luhn

If it fits the algorithm, it should have an output of true and if it doesn't, the output should be false. Any idea where it goes wrong?

I tried

```
1586455534096 ; output : false(fail)

49927398716 ; output : true (ok)

984697300577 ; output : false (fail)
```

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100];
  int n,num[100],prod[100],remainder,sum,total;
  scanf("%s", str);
  for(n=0;n<100;n++)
    {
      if(str[n]==0) break;
      num[n] = str[n] - '0';
      if(n%2!=0)
        {
          prod[n]=num[n]*2;
          sum=0;
          while(prod[n]>=10)
            {
              remainder=prod[n]%10;
              sum=sum+remainder;
              prod[n]=prod[n]/10;
            }
          num[n]=sum;
          }
      total = total + num[n];
      }
 if(total%10==0)
    printf("true\n");
  else
    printf("false\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code for a failing example?

Answer (score 3):

Your code working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100];
  int n,num[100],prod[100],remainder,sum,total=0;
  scanf("%s", str);
  for(n=0;n<100;n++)
    {
      if(str[n]==0) break;
      num[n] = str[n] - '0';
      if(n%2!=0)
        {
          prod[n]=num[n]*2;
          sum=0;
          while(prod[n]>0)
            {
              remainder=prod[n]%10;
              sum=sum+remainder;
              prod[n]=prod[n]/10;
            }
          num[n]=sum;
          }
      total = total + num[n];
      }
 if(total%10==0)
    printf("true\n");
  else
    printf("false\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Into your code there are 2 main problems:

1. no init value for total var at least
2. the inner while have to use `>0` as condition.

My correction on your code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char format[32];
    char str[100]={0};
    uint32_t n=0;
    uint32_t num = 0;
    uint32_t total=0;

    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%zus", (sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]))-1 );

    scanf(format, str);

    while (str[n] != '\0')
    {
        num = str[n] - '0';

        if(n%2!=0)
        {
            num*=2;
            while(num>0)
            {
                total += num%10;
                num/=10;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            total += num;
        }

        n++;
    }

    if(total%10==0)
        printf("true\n");
    else
        printf("false\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance `total` is uninitialized and having uninitialized values in the code leads to indeterminate values

Comment: Should I initialize total=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `total` before you use it, which means its value is *indeterminate* and giving you *undefined behavior*. Might be the same with other variables.

Initialize the variables on declaration, like e.g.

```
int n, num[100] = { 0 }, prod[100] = { 0 }, remainder = 0, sum = 0,total = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand. Do I put total=0 before any calculations?

Comment: Tried, but still failed.

Comment: @M.H.F Then you need to use a debugger to step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and values to see when and where it goes wrong. Start with some input that you *know* the values in each step, so you can easily verify.